# Sort by multiple column values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a shipment table in the following format:

| Shipment | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shipment 1 | Spain | France |
| shipment 2 | Landon | Germany |
| shipment 3 | Netherlands | Sweden |
| shipment 4 | Finland | France |
| shipment 6 | Landon | Belgium |
| shipment 7 | Landon | France |
| shipment 8 | Germany | France |
| shipment 9 | Landon | France |
| shipment 10 | Landon | France |
| shipment 11 | Germany | France |

How I can sort the above table with all the Germany to France appear first, then Landon to France followed by Landon to Germany, then the remaining shipments.

| Shipment | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shipment 11 | Germany | France |
| shipment 8 | Germany | France |
| shipment 7 | Landon | France |
| shipment 9 | Landon | France |
| shipment 10 | Landon | France |
| shipment 2 | Landon | Germany |
| shipment 1 | Spain | France |
| shipment 3 | Netherlands | Sweden |
| shipment 4 | Finland | France |
| shipment 6 | Landon | Belgium |

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use a `case` expression in the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the idea of using a `CASE` statement inside the `ORDER BY` clause, as already suggested in the comments:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Shipments
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN `Source` = 'Germany' AND `Destination` = 'France' THEN 1
         WHEN `Source` = 'Landon' AND `Destination` = 'France'  THEN 2
         WHEN `Source` = 'Landon' AND `Destination` = 'Germany' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
    END
```

Here's a fiddle too: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/58b3pWrUAeobtNd7yyUwwq/0.